# Installing apk in the middle of the app - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, auto-update

In my project in Andoird studio I would like to do an automatic application update. It won't be in the play store, so the In-app update drops out. I did everything until the notification application appears by the application with a notification of the new update. How can I do to download the APK file from my server and install? How do I do this?

Comment: There are many guides and questions about installing APK's programmatically already. And you can never do this without explicit user consent.

Comment: I know. I just mean that after downloading, he opened the file and that the user clicks install. Can you write me a link to the best post? 

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment so..)
Generality you will need a Dialog to show up to the user if his app version is old.
So when your app is start running check app version -> 
If (current_app_version == installed_app_version) -> Do nothing...
Else show a popup/dialog where you can create a download link to your app new version

Comment: I already have it. I mean a specific code that will be used to download and install updates.